# Angular, can't resolve all parameters for Component

Tags: angular, typescript

**Erros msg:**

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LoginCompComponent: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).
Evaluating src/main.ts
Booting application
```

The Component looks like this:

**IMPORTS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material';
import { MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material';
import { OverlayReference } from './overlay-ref';

import { UsersService } from '../service/users.service';
import { OverlayService } from '../service/overlay.service';
import {TranslatePipe} from '../service/translate.pipe';
import {TranslationService} from '../service/translation.service';
```

**CONSTRUCTOR:**

```
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private usersService: UsersService,
    //private overlay: OverlayService,
    public translationService: TranslationService,
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
) {}
```

Miracle is, if you comment the `overlay:OverlayService` it will work perfectly, and if I uncomment this line it will die, with the error message in the beginning. Any thoughts?

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c6bj5h) is a StackBlitz link, if you want to see the whole thing.

Comment: remove the comma after last parameter `public snackBar: MatSnackBar`

Comment: have you marked your service as `@Injectable` ?

Comment: @eduPeeth still not working

Comment: @OlegI Yes I have

Comment: @Skickpause is your service in the same module with the component?

Comment: @OlegI No, it's in an other service folder

Comment: @Skickpause I'm asking about `NgModule`. If it is not, you need to import it

Comment: The problem is with this line: `const filePreviewPortal = new ComponentPortal(LoginCompComponent);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You import `import { LoginCompComponent } from '../login-comp/login-comp.component'` in **OverlayService** and you also import `import { OverlayService } from '../service/overlay.service';` in **LoginComponent**.

Very very bad practise :) Need to refactor this

Comment: Then how should I call the close function in the OverlayService, from the OverLay (LoginComp)? I want to call it right after the user presses the login button

Comment: Not familiar with your project. Maybe you could create another service and move `open(config: FilePreviewDialogConfig = {}) {` there

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency between your TypeScript modules: OverlayService imports LoginComponent, and LoginComponent imports OverlayService.

Refactor the code to avoid that.